# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, PosixPath found

Tags: python, python-2.7, path

I am opening a file by providing path as PosixPath.

```
from pathlib import Path

SOURCE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent  
ROOT_DIR = SOURCE_DIR.parent
DATA_DIR = ROOT_DIR / "data"

with open(DATA_DIR / "filename.txt", "r") as f:
    VALUES = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
```

I get the following error: `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, PosixPath found`.

How can I convert the whole path to string (from PosixPath) or open a PosixPath file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your `Path` to a string. Simply do:

```
open(str(DATA_DIR / "filename.txt"), "r")
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Path.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=open#pathlib.Path.open):

```
with (DATA_DIR / "filename.txt").open() as f:
```